# Is there a performance gain if I use/return JSON.Serialize(List<Account>)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I would like to understand if there is a performance gain if I return the 
serialized List of sObjects instead of List of sObjects from a @AuraEnabled function.

```
public PerformanceClass {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccountsList(){
        return [select Id from Account Limit 2];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getAccountsString(){
        List<Account> accList =  [select Id from Account Limit 2];
        return JSON.serialize(accList);
    }

}
```

Which one is more efficient here and advised to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You may as well return the list directly. Apex Code JSON's utilities are slower than the automatic JSON parsing, *and* your newly minted String is going to be JSON-serialized again anyways.

Comment: I have observed at times that, due to some apex class serialization issue, data wasn't returning properly to client. In that case, I have serialized to String and in Javascript deserialized into object.

Comment: @datasert Yes, but that's a hack I'd reserve for when I need to.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox. one doubt though, "newly minted String is going to be JSON-serialized again anyways".. Why will it serialize again?

Comment: @amidstCloud the response to a method is returned via JSON, so you end up with something like this: `{"actions": [{"id":"...", "state":"SUCCESS","returnValue": ...},{"id":.......}]}"` If you return a String, it's still JSON encoded (primarily escaping quote symbols) because otherwise it'd be misinterpreted.